# How to connect with multi region private subnets through single VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I had created 3 VPC's in three regions and I configured VPC peering between this 3 regions and it's working fine I can ping all the servers from any region through private ip's, I had configured openvpn in 'A' region my intension is to connect to all 3 region private networks using single VPN connection from my home network. But through that VPN I can connect only to instances present in VPC 'A' region, how can I connect to all 3 regions private subnets through one VPN connection?

**VPC A (172.16.0.0/16) Ohio,
VPC B (172.32.0.0/16) California,
VPB C (10.100.0.0/16) Ireland,**
This are my 3 VPC's. To connect all three VPC's, I used vpcpeering **"A-->B,A-->C,B-->C"** by this I connected all my three regions network internally from any region I can ping any private instance among all the three regions upto here it's worked fine. Now to connect all this three region's private instances from my home network I configured openvpn in VPC A. But from this I can connect only to private instances within VPC A, I can't connect to VPC B and VPC C how can I connect to all the instances among all regions from VPN connection that I created in VPC A.

Comment: Seems like whatever you use to connect between regions dosen't listen on all interfaces and the tunnel interface for the VPN can't access anything outside region A. Without more information and configurations we can't really help you in detail though.

Comment: I breifie the question now. Can you help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is called transitive peering which is not supported (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html#transitive-peering).

For your configuration to work, you need to have an instance running a VPN (OpenVPN for example) on each VPC (A --> B and A --> C) that will extend VPC A to B and C. And your VPN (from home) to VPC A will see VPC B and C as "part" of VPC A.